# Mysql check combination through different rows

Tags: mysql, exists

So I have the below table and one variable in php that has these values: 14,16

[combo table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PDUN.png)

How can I check if the above combination of numbers exist in the table? The above combo exists with the id 3. I don't want to check the order of numbers (ex. "16,14" or "14,16")

I hope you will not be confused!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to ***research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself*** before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Comment: Both 3 and 4 have 14 and 16 not only 3?!!

Answer (score 2):

You just need `GROUP BY` with `COUNT` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT id
FROM tablename
WHERE optid IN(14, 16)
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT optid) = 2;
```

- `WHERE optid IN(14, 16)` will ensure that id have those numbers.
- `COUNT DISTINCT` will remove all id expect those that have exactly two `optid`.

[demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/533225/1)

Results:

```
| id |
|----|
|  3 |
|  4 |
```

**Note that:** this query will give you those `id` that have at least `14 and 16`. So it will give you both 3 and 4.

However if you want those that have exactly 14 and 16 and no more thing, then try this:

```
SELECT id
FROM tablename
WHERE optid IN(14, 16)
  AND id not in (SELECT id from tablename where optid not in(14,16))
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT optid) = 2;
```

This will give you:

```
| id |
|----|
|  3 |
```

[Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/533225/6)